# ionic responsive col for list item

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

Try to resize:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxGbbx

```
<ion-content>
  <ul class="list">
    <a class="item" ng-repeat="thread in data" ng-href="{{thread.url}}" target="_blank">
      <li class="">
        {{thread.title}}
        <span class="desc">{{thread.desc}}</span>
        <span class="item-note badge badge-assertive">{{thread.replies}}</span>
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

Where should I apply the class of 'row responsive-sm' and the class of 'col'? I tried to play around but still doesn't work. my thread.title is too long and overflowed the screen.

Comment: Do you have a link to your site or an example?

Comment: @Gezzasa http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxGbbx

try to resize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you want to apply the grid structure to each list item..

So, here's how you can play with row and cols.

```
<ul class="list">
  <a class="item" ng-repeat="thread in data track by $index" ng-href="{{thread.url}}" target="_blank">
    <li class="row">
      <div class="col col-80">
        <span class="row responsive-sm item-text-wrap">{{thread.title}}</span>
        <span class="row responsive-sm">{{thread.desc}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <span class="item-note badge badge-assertive">{{thread.replies}}</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Updated Plunker [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEOPqJ)

Comment: is the track by $index important in my case?